# Can Rhonas the Indomitable attack if I pump Voltaic Brawler?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have a [Voltaic Brawler](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVoltaic%20Brawler%5d) (3/2) on board and also a [Rhonas the Indomitable](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRhonas%20the%20Indomitable%5d).
I am going to pump the brawler up with an energy counter to make the brawler a (4/3) and attack with the brawler.  Will Rhonas also be able to attack now?

Answer (score 10):

You can't get Rhonas attacking that way, unfortunately. This is because of how we handle declaring attackers:

1. We enter the Declare Attackers step.
2. You choose attackers. They're declared attackers simultaneously. (At this point, Voltaic Brawler can attack, but Rhonas cannot.)
3. The active player receives priority, and in the process of them receiving it, triggered abilities go on the stack, including Voltaic Brawler's.
4. You get the opportunity to choose to pump Voltaic Brawler with +1/+1.

At this point, declaring attackers is done. You can't declare new ones. It's too late.

This would be different if you used Rhonas's activated ability before combat to get a 5/2 Voltaic Brawler before declaring attackers. (That's exactly what it's there for: to benefit your strategy and help Rhonas attack. Every Amonkhet god has an activated ability that moves you closer to them being able to attack and block.)

Answer (score 4):

You will not be able to do that.  Voltaic Brawler's ability starts with the word 'Whenever' which means it is a triggered ability that goes on the stack.  It will wait to go on the stack until all attacks have been declared and the active player gets priority in the declare attackers step.  At this point you can't "go back" to declare more attackers after choosing to pay the cost.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot attack with Rhonas in that scenario.

The steps of combat are:

1. Beginning of Combat
2. Declare Attackers
3. Declare Blockers
4. Combat Damage
5. End of Combat

You only get to attack once, at the very beginning of Declare Attackers.  Nobody has priority, so no spells and abilities can be activated.  Once you have declared attackers, then Brawler's trigger goes on the stack. Then you can pump it, but the opportunity for Rhonas to attack has passed.

Answer (score 2):

In general, Rhonas only cares whether you have a creature whose current power is 4 or greater, taking into account pump effects. In this particular case, pumping Voltaic Brawler by spending energy on its triggered ability will not allow you to attack with Rhonas.

By the time the Brawler's ability triggers and you have the opportunity to pay energy, you have already finished declaring attackers. You can't "go back" and also declare Rhonas as an attacker now that you control another creature with power 4 or greater.